# $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a number where: $\forall r>0$, $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p-r<n+\frac{1}{2n}<p+r$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a number with the following property:

For every $r>0$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|p - (n + \frac{1}{2n})|<r$.

I am trying to show that $p$ can be written as $p = m + \frac{1}{2m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

MY ATTEMPT:

I was able to reduce the inequality $|p - (n + \frac{1}{2n})|<r$ as follows:

$\implies \ \ \ \ -r < p - (n + \frac{1}{2n}) < r$

$\implies \ \ \ \ n+\frac{1}{2n} - r < p < n+\frac{1}{2n} - r$

$\implies \ \ \ \ p-r<n+\frac{1}{2n}<p+r$

I am having huge troubles proving this. A possibly useful relation:

$x + \frac{1}{2x} = y \ \ \ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \ \ \ x = \frac{1}{2}y \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{ y^{2} - 2 }$

A possible idea I had is to write $p = m + \frac{1}{2m} + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I should probably be introducing an extra bound on $\epsilon$, but I'm not sure what exaclyt. I would assume that writing $p$ in this manner would force $\epsilon = 0$.

Does anyone have some ideas where to take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the function $y=x+\frac 1{2x}$ is increasing for $x>1$; Take the infimum of $|p - (n + \frac{1}{2n})|$ and show that it must be zero. Indeed if the infimum $\delta$ is not zero for $n\in\mathbb N$, then you can choose $r=\frac\delta2 $ and arrive at contradiction. This infimum is actually a minimum because $|p - (n + \frac{1}{2n})|$ is increasing from all $n>N_0$ for some $N_0$.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists an $n$ such that $|p - (n + \frac{1}{2n})| < r$ for every $r > 0$ then $p = n + \frac{1}{2n}$.

It might become clearer if we restate the more general claim: If $|x - y| < \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$ then $x = y$.

Comment: For every $r>0$, there is $n_r$ such that. So $n$ depends on $r$.

Comment: Yes, but it must be the same $n_r$ for all sufficiently small $r$.

Comment: Then that must be shown.

Comment: I am happy with leaving that as an exercise for the reader. :)